# Get properties by reflection, but only user made propertes in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm doing something using reflection in recursive function.

I want to get the properties that only I made.

```
public class Sample
{
    string versionInfo { get; set; } = "0.1.2.3";
}

var props_1 = typeof(Sample).GetProperties();
var props_2 = typeof(string).GetProperties();
```

I mean, I want to get one property in props_1 and I don't want to get any properties in props_2 because I didn't make anything to string type.

I've done something using "BindingFlags". But I can't get what I want to do it.

Please give me a wisdom you have.

Thank you.

Comment: Your example is quite nonsensical as string is sealed and even if you really wanted you cannot have of your own properties.

Comment: are you talking about inherited properties in a class that you have implemented? please clarify. Up to now we are playing a guessing game

Comment: Side note: Why `string`? `Version versionInfo {get; set;} = new Version("0.1.2.3");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your purpose is to omit properties that are not part of your assembly, just check your assembly name against the type of the reflected property

```
 var properties= typeof(Sample).GetProperties();
        var myAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName;
        foreach(var prop in properties)
        {
            if (Assembly.GetAssembly(prop.PropertyType).FullName.Equals(myAssembly))
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);// this belongs to your assembly
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @PepitoSh pointed out, your request is unclear on that. So I reinterpreted your question as: *how can I get only properties declared by me, not coming from inherited classes*?

About this one, you are probably looking for [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netstandard-1.6#System_Reflection_BindingFlags_DeclaredOnly). Here is an example:

```
public class Tester
{
    public string SuperProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Test : Tester
{
    public string SubProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var props = typeof(Test).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name); // print only SubProperty
    }
}
```